# Return a 'string' from javascript eval() function

Tags: string, eval

I am trying to evaluate an expression like `a == b ? 'Ok' : 'Cancel';` using JavaScript `eval()` but is shows error.

Is there any way to execute and return string out of `eval()` ?

Regards,
Nwbrd

Answer (score 3):

Your error is likely related to `a` or `b` being not defined prior to calling `eval()`, for ex: the following code works fine with the `eval()` call *returning* a string as expected.

```
var a = 5, b = 6;
var result = eval("a == b ? 'SAME' : 'DIFFERENT'");
alert(result);
```